# Logitech G Hub Jump Script

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have been trying to make a script that works like this

Enable with scroll lock

Hold space = Press Space every 20ms

I have the G3 key as a placeholder for space because I can't figure out how to do a                      if PressKey("space") type thing

Heres what I have so far

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 3) and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
PressKey("spacebar")
sleep(20)
ReleaseKey("spacebar")
repeat
until not (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 3)
end
end
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lua, but I think your `repeat` syntax is wrong. The documentation says it's `repeat \n (statement) \n until (condition)`: https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.3.html but you have `repeat \n until (condition )`.

Comment: `repeat until condition` is a correct Lua statement.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to do a if PressKey("space") type thing

LGS/GHUB is unable to monitor press/release of usual keys (letters, digits, spacebar) on your keyboard.
Such feature would make possible to write a keylogger script in Lua, and Logitech wants to prevent this.

> Hold G3 = Press Space every 20ms

You don't need to write Lua code for this.
Just bind G3 to a looped macro.
Set "toggle" as macro's type to stop the macro by pressing G3 again.
Of course, such macro would ignore ScrollLock.